# C++ how to read what I want from a file?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

How can I assign a variable from my C++ code a value from a structured .txt file for example?
If I have this following input.txt structured like this:

```
    <Name> "John Washington"
    <Age> "24"
    <ID> "19702408447417"
    <Alive Status> "Deceased"
```

In my c++ code if I have

```
ifstream read("input.txt",ios::in);
char name[64];
read>>name;//name will point to John Washington string
int age;
read>>age;// cout<<age will return 24;
int ID;
read>>ID;// cout<<ID will return 19702408447417
char Alivestatus[32];
read>>Alivestatus;//Alivestatus will point to Deceased string;
```

How can I make it work like above?

Comment: Perhaps you have a good reason to be using C-style char arrays, but I would recommend using `std::string` instead, just as a general C++ software tip.

Comment: I will consider using std::string instead but I am so used with char variable types...

Comment: @xQd You'll need to implement an appropriate parser for this text file format. _"but I am so used with char variable types."_ Get unused from this behavior when writing c++ code!

Comment: 19702408447417 will also overflow a 32-bit integer. Perhaps consider using larger data types, or even std::string for that.

Comment: @Alejandro Lucena Of course I will use larger data types.That code was just for the sake of making an simple example. @ πάντα ῥεῖ Never heard of such thing as parsing text tile format...could you provide some links which contain tutorials for beginners like me?

Comment: Here is a link for c++ text file parsing:http://cs.dvc.edu/HowTo_Cparse.html

Comment: Possible duplicates: [c++ reading data from text file](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+structure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @ sam2090 thanks for the link! Will have a read of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @πάντα ῥεῖ mentioned in the comments, you will need to implement a parser that can interpret the `<>` tags within your file. Additionally, I would recommend reconsidering the data types.

Specifically, given that there's no special reason that you're using `char []`, please switch to `std::string`. I don't know the use case of your code, but if the `input.txt` happens to contain data thats larger than the size of the arrays, or even worse if the input is user-controlled, this can easily lead to Buffer Overflows and unwanted exploits. `std::string` also has the benefit of being standardized, optimized, much more friendly than char arrays, and has a variety of useful algorithms and functions  readily available for use.

With regards to text file parsing, you can perhaps implement the following:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream input_file("input.txt");

        std::string name_delimeter("<Name> ");
        std::string age_delimeter("<Age> ");
        std::string id_delimeter("<ID> ");
        std::string alive_delimeter("<Alive Status> ");


        std::string line;

        std::getline(input_file,line);

        std::string name(line,line.find(name_delimeter) + name_delimeter.size()); // string for the reasons described above

        std::getline(input_file,line);

        int age = std::atoi(line.substr(line.find(age_delimeter) + age_delimeter.size()).c_str());

        std::getline(input_file,line);

        std::string id(line,line.find(id_delimeter) + id_delimeter.size()); // the example ID overflows 32-bit integer
                                                                            // maybe representing is a string is more appropriate

        std::getline(input_file,line);

        std::string alive_status(line,line.find(alive_delimeter) + alive_delimeter.size()); // string for the same reason as name


        std::cout << "Name = " << name << std::endl << "Age = " << age << std::endl << "ID = " << id << std::endl << "Alive? " << alive_status << std::endl;
    }
```

The basis of the code is just to read the file as it is structured and construct the appropriate data types from them. In fact, because I used std::string for most of the data types, it was easy to build the correct output by means of std::string's constructors and available functions.

Maybe you are performing this in a loop, or the file has several structures. To approach this problem, you can make a `Record` class that overloads `operator >>` and reads in the data as required.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro for this useful information.I want the input file to contain structured data because I have a lot of input information and I needed an easier way to see and write the input data for my assignment program.Cheers !